# why does gnome 3 lag in all distributions?

Tags: performance, gnome3, gnome-shell, intel-graphics

For some reason every single animation in gnome 3 lags a lot on my laptop (lenovo e330). I have tried the most recent version of a lot of different distros: ubuntu gnome, debian, centos, antergos, fedora, opensuse, zorin, arch but they have the same performance problem with gnome. My laptop is reasonably powerful: core i3, 8gb ram and intel 3000 graphics. I have no lag whatsoever in windows 10, ubuntu with unity, any kde distro so this seems to be a gnome problem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Thats simply how it is. Gnome has laggy animations. Partial solution is to install impatience and remove all other extensions.